# CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 problem install gd-devel

Tags: installation, centos, yum

I need to install the gd-devel package on CentOS 7.9.2009

However it presents some error messages and I can't solve it.

I tried to install via .rpm, same problem, I see that the versions are newer but I don't want to use old versions

root@node2021 ~ $ cat / etc / redhat-release
CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)

```
root@node2021 ~ $ yum install gd-devel

    Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, ovl Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile  * base: centos.mirror.letscloud.io  * centos-sclo-rh: centos.mirror.letscloud.io  * epel: d2lzkl7pfhq30w.cloudfront.net  * extras: centos.mirror.letscloud.io  * updates: mirror.ufscar.br Resolving Dependencies
    --> Running transaction check
    ---> Package gd-devel.x86_64 0:2.0.35-27.el7_9 will be installed
    --> Processing Dependency: gd = 2.0.35-27.el7_9 for package: gd-devel-2.0.35-27.el7_9.x86_64
    --> Processing Dependency: libpng-devel for package: gd-devel-2.0.35-27.el7_9.x86_64
    --> Processing Dependency: libjpeg-devel for package: gd-devel-2.0.35-27.el7_9.x86_64
    --> Processing Dependency: libXpm-devel for package: gd-devel-2.0.35-27.el7_9.x86_64
    --> Processing Dependency: libX11-devel for package: gd-devel-2.0.35-27.el7_9.x86_64
    --> Processing Dependency: freetype-devel for package: gd-devel-2.0.35-27.el7_9.x86_64
    --> Processing Dependency: fontconfig-devel for package: gd-devel-2.0.35-27.el7_9.x86_64
    --> Processing Dependency: libgd.so.2()(64bit) for package: gd-devel-2.0.35-27.el7_9.x86_64
    --> Running transaction check
    ---> Package fontconfig-devel.x86_64 0:2.13.0-4.3.el7 will be installed
    --> Processing Dependency: fontconfig(x86-64) = 2.13.0-4.3.el7 for package: fontconfig-devel-2.13.0-4.3.el7.x86_64
    --> Processing Dependency: pkgconfig(uuid) for package: fontconfig-devel-2.13.0-4.3.el7.x86_64
    ---> Package freetype-devel.x86_64 0:2.8-14.el7_9.1 will be installed
    --> Processing Dependency: freetype = 2.8-14.el7_9.1 for package: freetype-devel-2.8-14.el7_9.1.x86_64
    ---> Package gd.i686 0:2.0.35-27.el7_9 will be installed
    --> Processing Dependency: libz.so.1 for package: gd-2.0.35-27.el7_9.i686
    --> Processing Dependency: libpng15.so.15(PNG15_0) for package: gd-2.0.35-27.el7_9.i686
    --> Processing Dependency: libpng15.so.15 for package: gd-2.0.35-27.el7_9.i686
    --> Processing Dependency: libm.so.6(GLIBC_2.1) for package: gd-2.0.35-27.el7_9.i686
    --> Processing Dependency: libm.so.6(GLIBC_2.0) for package: gd-2.0.35-27.el7_9.i686
    --> Processing Dependency: libm.so.6 for package: gd-2.0.35-27.el7_9.i686
    --> Processing Dependency: libjpeg.so.62(LIBJPEG_6.2) for package: gd-2.0.35-27.el7_9.i686
    --> Processing Dependency: libjpeg.so.62 for package: gd-2.0.35-27.el7_9.i686
    --> Processing Dependency: libfontconfig.so.1 for package: gd-2.0.35-27.el7_9.i686
    --> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.11) for package: gd-2.0.35-27.el7_9.i686
    --> Processing Dependency: libXpm.so.4 for package: gd-2.0.35-27.el7_9.i686
    --> Processing Dependency: libX11.so.6 for package: gd-2.0.35-27.el7_9.i686
    ---> Package gd-devel.x86_64 0:2.0.35-27.el7_9 will be installed
    --> Processing Dependency: libgd.so.2()(64bit) for package: gd-devel-2.0.35-27.el7_9.x86_64
    ---> Package libX11-devel.x86_64 0:1.6.7-3.el7_9 will be installed
    --> Processing Dependency: pkgconfig(xcb) >= 1.11.1 for package: libX11-devel-1.6.7-3.el7_9.x86_64
    --> Processing Dependency: pkgconfig(xproto) for package: libX11-devel-1.6.7-3.el7_9.x86_64
    --> Processing Dependency: pkgconfig(xcb) for package: libX11-devel-1.6.7-3.el7_9.x86_64
    --> Processing Dependency: pkgconfig(kbproto) for package: libX11-devel-1.6.7-3.el7_9.x86_64
    ---> Package libXpm-devel.x86_64 0:3.5.12-1.el7 will be installed
    ---> Package libjpeg-turbo-devel.x86_64 0:1.2.90-8.el7 will be installed
    --> Processing Dependency: libjpeg-turbo(x86-64) = 1.2.90-8.el7 for package: libjpeg-turbo-devel-1.2.90-8.el7.x86_64
    ---> Package libpng-devel.x86_64 2:1.5.13-8.el7 will be installed
    --> Processing Dependency: libpng(x86-64) = 2:1.5.13-8.el7 for package: 2:libpng-devel-1.5.13-8.el7.x86_64
    --> Running transaction check
    ---> Package fontconfig.i686 0:2.13.0-4.3.el7 will be installed
    --> Processing Dependency: libuuid.so.1(UUID_1.0) for package: fontconfig-2.13.0-4.3.el7.i686
    --> Processing Dependency: libuuid.so.1 for package: fontconfig-2.13.0-4.3.el7.i686
    --> Processing Dependency: libexpat.so.1 for package: fontconfig-2.13.0-4.3.el7.i686
    --> Processing Dependency: dejavu-sans-fonts for package: fontconfig-2.13.0-4.3.el7.i686
    ---> Package fontconfig-devel.x86_64 0:2.13.0-4.3.el7 will be installed
    --> Processing Dependency: fontconfig(x86-64) = 2.13.0-4.3.el7 for package: fontconfig-devel-2.13.0-4.3.el7.x86_64
    ---> Package freetype.i686 0:2.8-14.el7_9.1 will be installed
    --> Processing Dependency: libbz2.so.1 for package: freetype-2.8-14.el7_9.1.i686
    ---> Package gd-devel.x86_64 0:2.0.35-27.el7_9 will be installed
    --> Processing Dependency: libgd.so.2()(64bit) for package: gd-devel-2.0.35-27.el7_9.x86_64
    ---> Package glibc.i686 0:2.17-324.el7_9 will be installed
    --> Processing Dependency: libfreebl3.so(NSSRAWHASH_3.12.3) for package: glibc-2.17-324.el7_9.i686
    --> Processing Dependency: libfreebl3.so for package: glibc-2.17-324.el7_9.i686
    ---> Package libX11.i686 0:1.6.7-3.el7_9 will be installed
    --> Processing Dependency: libxcb.so.1 for package: libX11-1.6.7-3.el7_9.i686
    ---> Package libXpm.i686 0:3.5.12-1.el7 will be installed
    ---> Package libjpeg-turbo.i686 0:1.2.90-8.el7 will be installed
    ---> Package libjpeg-turbo-devel.x86_64 0:1.2.90-8.el7 will be installed
    --> Processing Dependency: libjpeg-turbo(x86-64) = 1.2.90-8.el7 for package: libjpeg-turbo-devel-1.2.90-8.el7.x86_64
    ---> Package libpng.i686 2:1.5.13-8.el7 will be installed
    ---> Package libpng-devel.x86_64 2:1.5.13-8.el7 will be installed
    --> Processing Dependency: libpng(x86-64) = 2:1.5.13-8.el7 for package: 2:libpng-devel-1.5.13-8.el7.x86_64
    ---> Package libuuid-devel.x86_64 0:2.23.2-65.el7_9.1 will be installed
    ---> Package libxcb-devel.x86_64 0:1.13-1.el7 will be installed
    --> Processing Dependency: libxcb(x86-64) = 1.13-1.el7 for package: libxcb-devel-1.13-1.el7.x86_64
    --> Processing Dependency: pkgconfig(xau) >= 0.99.2 for package: libxcb-devel-1.13-1.el7.x86_64
    --> Processing Dependency: libxcb-xevie.so.0()(64bit) for package: libxcb-devel-1.13-1.el7.x86_64
    ---> Package xorg-x11-proto-devel.noarch 0:2018.4-1.el7 will be installed
    ---> Package zlib.i686 0:1.2.7-19.el7_9 will be installed
    --> Running transaction check
    ---> Package bzip2-libs.i686 0:1.0.6-13.el7 will be installed
    ---> Package dejavu-sans-fonts.noarch 0:2.33-6.el7 will be installed
    --> Processing Dependency: dejavu-fonts-common = 2.33-6.el7 for package: dejavu-sans-fonts-2.33-6.el7.noarch
    ---> Package expat.i686 0:2.1.0-12.el7 will be installed
    ---> Package fontconfig-devel.x86_64 0:2.13.0-4.3.el7 will be installed
    --> Processing Dependency: fontconfig(x86-64) = 2.13.0-4.3.el7 for package: fontconfig-devel-2.13.0-4.3.el7.x86_64
    ---> Package gd-devel.x86_64 0:2.0.35-27.el7_9 will be installed
    --> Processing Dependency: libgd.so.2()(64bit) for package: gd-devel-2.0.35-27.el7_9.x86_64
    ---> Package libXau-devel.x86_64 0:1.0.8-2.1.el7 will be installed
    --> Processing Dependency: libXau = 1.0.8-2.1.el7 for package: libXau-devel-1.0.8-2.1.el7.x86_64
    ---> Package libjpeg-turbo-devel.x86_64 0:1.2.90-8.el7 will be installed
    --> Processing Dependency: libjpeg-turbo(x86-64) = 1.2.90-8.el7 for package: libjpeg-turbo-devel-1.2.90-8.el7.x86_64
    ---> Package libpng-devel.x86_64 2:1.5.13-8.el7 will be installed
    --> Processing Dependency: libpng(x86-64) = 2:1.5.13-8.el7 for package: 2:libpng-devel-1.5.13-8.el7.x86_64
    ---> Package libuuid.i686 0:2.23.2-65.el7_9.1 will be installed
    ---> Package libxcb.i686 0:1.13-1.el7 will be installed
    ---> Package libxcb-devel.x86_64 0:1.13-1.el7 will be installed
    --> Processing Dependency: libxcb(x86-64) = 1.13-1.el7 for package: libxcb-devel-1.13-1.el7.x86_64
    --> Processing Dependency: libxcb-xevie.so.0()(64bit) for package: libxcb-devel-1.13-1.el7.x86_64
    ---> Package nss-softokn-freebl.i686 0:3.53.1-6.el7_9 will be installed
    --> Running transaction check
    ---> Package dejavu-fonts-common.noarch 0:2.33-6.el7 will be installed
    ---> Package fontconfig-devel.x86_64 0:2.13.0-4.3.el7 will be installed
    --> Processing Dependency: fontconfig(x86-64) = 2.13.0-4.3.el7 for package: fontconfig-devel-2.13.0-4.3.el7.x86_64
    ---> Package gd-devel.x86_64 0:2.0.35-27.el7_9 will be installed
    --> Processing Dependency: libgd.so.2()(64bit) for package: gd-devel-2.0.35-27.el7_9.x86_64
    ---> Package libXau.i686 0:1.0.8-2.1.el7 will be installed
    ---> Package libjpeg-turbo-devel.x86_64 0:1.2.90-8.el7 will be installed
    --> Processing Dependency: libjpeg-turbo(x86-64) = 1.2.90-8.el7 for package: libjpeg-turbo-devel-1.2.90-8.el7.x86_64
    ---> Package libpng-devel.x86_64 2:1.5.13-8.el7 will be installed
    --> Processing Dependency: libpng(x86-64) = 2:1.5.13-8.el7 for package: 2:libpng-devel-1.5.13-8.el7.x86_64
    ---> Package libxcb-devel.x86_64 0:1.13-1.el7 will be installed
    --> Processing Dependency: libxcb(x86-64) = 1.13-1.el7 for package: libxcb-devel-1.13-1.el7.x86_64
    --> Processing Dependency: libxcb-xevie.so.0()(64bit) for package: libxcb-devel-1.13-1.el7.x86_64
    --> Finished Dependency Resolution Error: Package: gd-devel-2.0.35-27.el7_9.x86_64 (updates)
               Requires: libgd.so.2()(64bit)
               Available: gd-2.0.35-26.el7.x86_64 (base)
                   libgd.so.2()(64bit)
               Available: gd-2.0.35-27.el7_9.x86_64 (updates)
                   libgd.so.2()(64bit)
               Installed: gd-2.2.5-1.el7.centos.fuzzyrpm.x86_64 (@fuzzyrpm)
                  ~libgd.so.3()(64bit) Error: Package: libjpeg-turbo-devel-1.2.90-8.el7.x86_64 (base)
               Requires: libjpeg-turbo(x86-64) = 1.2.90-8.el7
               Installed: libjpeg-turbo-2.0.4-1.el7.fuzzyrpm.x86_64 (@fuzzyrpm)
                   libjpeg-turbo(x86-64) = 2.0.4-1.el7.fuzzyrpm
               Available: libjpeg-turbo-1.2.90-8.el7.x86_64 (base)
                   libjpeg-turbo(x86-64) = 1.2.90-8.el7 Error: Package: fontconfig-devel-2.13.0-4.3.el7.x86_64 (base)
               Requires: fontconfig(x86-64) = 2.13.0-4.3.el7
               Installed: fontconfig-2.13.1-4.el7.fuzzyrpm.x86_64 (@fuzzyrpm)
                   fontconfig(x86-64) = 2.13.1-4.el7.fuzzyrpm
               Available: fontconfig-2.13.0-4.3.el7.x86_64 (base)
                   fontconfig(x86-64) = 2.13.0-4.3.el7 Error: Package: libxcb-devel-1.13-1.el7.x86_64 (base)
               Requires: libxcb(x86-64) = 1.13-1.el7
               Installed: libxcb-1.13.1-1.el7.fuzzyrpm.x86_64 (@fuzzyrpm)
                   libxcb(x86-64) = 1.13.1-1.el7.fuzzyrpm
               Available: libxcb-1.13-1.el7.x86_64 (base)
                   libxcb(x86-64) = 1.13-1.el7 Error: Package: libxcb-devel-1.13-1.el7.x86_64 (base)
               Requires: libxcb-xevie.so.0()(64bit)
               Available: libxcb-1.13-1.el7.x86_64 (base)
                   libxcb-xevie.so.0()(64bit)
               Installed: libxcb-1.13.1-1.el7.fuzzyrpm.x86_64 (@fuzzyrpm)
                   Not found Error: Package: 2:libpng-devel-1.5.13-8.el7.x86_64 (base)
               Requires: libpng(x86-64) = 2:1.5.13-8.el7
               Installed: 2:libpng-1.6.37-1.el7.fuzzyrpm.x86_64 (@fuzzyrpm)
                   libpng(x86-64) = 2:1.6.37-1.el7.fuzzyrpm
               Available: 2:libpng-1.5.13-8.el7.x86_64 (base)
                   libpng(x86-64) = 2:1.5.13-8.el7  You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem  You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Any solution?

I did not find how to solve this problem!

Answer (score 0):

#### Overview:

This issue normally occurs when you have higher version of the dependencies already (or version from another repo with a different naming convention)

Example from your error output:

```
    Requires: libjpeg-turbo(x86-64) = 1.2.90-8.el7
    Installed: libjpeg-turbo-2.0.4-1.el7.fuzzyrpm.x86_64 (@fuzzyrpm)
    libjpeg-turbo(x86-64) = 2.0.4-1.el7.fuzzyrpm
```

As a dependency of `gd-devel`, yum sees that it requires `libjpeg-turbo(x86-64) 1.2.90-8.el7` however, it finds out that a higher version `libjpeg-turbo(x86-64) = 2.0.4-1.el7.fuzzyrpm` [or a version from another repo (generally different naming convention) is already installed.

Now it is says, deal with your problem manually I do NOT want to be intelligent here.

#### Resolution:

Option 1 (easiest one):

Install with --skip-broken flag
[WARNING: Ensure you have snapshotted the system before you do this. In case the system gets messed up]

Option 2 (easy one):

One good option to go ahead without tampering your current working system is to build from source.

Option 3 (tedious one):

Find out what has installed these packages, uninstall them.
Then preferably disable fuzzyrpm repo
Then install gd.devel

Further details depend on the option you make

Comment: I still couldn't solve it, do you have the commands step by step?

Comment: I suggest Option 2 and it is well documented in  the below link
https://noknow.info/it/os/install_libgd_from_source

If you want to go for different versions, you can try browsing through different releases under:
https://github.com/libgd/libgd/releases/
Hope that helps